# How does debian/ubuntu knows a package has a updated version

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

If my understanding is good, with `apt update`, Debian download a release file and with this file, it can tell if a package needs to be upgraded and with which dependencies. How does it do this? Th release file seems to be just a list of hashes so I don't quite understand.

Sorry, I don't have a very good English.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whilst `apt update` can download one or more `Release` files, the primary files it is downloading are `Packages` file(s).  Those files contain the full list of available packages, their versions, and other metadata (like dependencies).  Once apt has a list of available packages and their versions, it is a straightforward matter of comparison to determine which packages have versions newer than those currently installed.

Answer (score 5):

Package lists are the Packages and Sources files. These contain the debian/control file content for every package in the repository. From these metadata APT can determine a dependency solution.

Releases is a description of the entire archive and signature data.

Debian reference manual, [Chapter 2. Debian package management](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_debian_package_management_internals)